# Why my Google Playstore IAP application always use Test Card, even when I use real product ID and with any other account

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I create application with IAP feature for Android with Unity, I have set up everything and tested it and its already works in testing environment with my tester account.

But when I test with real product ID and upload it on Open Testing (Beta), and login with any other account that is not include as tester, the app still offers pay with test card, I want to test it with real cards or any store option.

for case above, I use android 10, and when I use my other phone that is on android 7, it never use test card, even with my tester account O_o

anybody knows about this or experience the same thing?

or it will only get out the test card if I publish it to production?
(right now its on Open Testing on google dev console)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6vXg.jpg

Comment: Is your app released or still in testing (closed beta or closed alpha). The Test Card will always show up for the developer account that is linked with your Google Dev Console. If you have released the app, try a fresh install and signing in/out of the account. Google caches a bunch of data all the time. I suppose before the full fresh install, try clearing the cache of the app.

Comment: the app still in "Open Testing" on google console, (the google didnt use beta and alpha anymore), and I already use any other account or even a fresh account, but still can't get out that test card. even in my friend's device it showed the test card

Comment: Google has Internal Testing, Closed Testing, and an Open Beta. Or are you just saying your app specifically is not in those tracks and is currently in the Open Testing? No real purchases can be made in an app until it is fully released. Until it is in production and not on a testing track, it should only show the Test Card as far as I know.

Comment: Yes its on "open testing", google dont use the open "open beta" anymore. Ok so its because its not on production channel yet, ok thanks for your answer. Going to release on production ASAP